# Check to see if a c# method is used

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find unused code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245963/find-unused-code)

I am wanting to go through our solution and remove any unused code. I have several projects included in this solution and do not want to go one by one. I am using Visual Studio 10, .net 4.

Is there a tool that will tell me where all the unused methods are?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245963/find-unused-code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020297/visual-studio-2008-c-how-to-find-dead-code-in-a-project

Comment: It looks like there is a long chain of duplicate questions ending in http://stackoverflow.com/q/65585/357812

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resharper will; unless you want a report generated. iirc FxCop will too.

EDIT: related question: [Visual Studio 2008 / C# : How to find dead code in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020297/visual-studio-2008-c-how-to-find-dead-code-in-a-project)

Comment: +1 Resharper is one of the most useful tools that I'd now hate to do without.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) has some features that can do that - I am not sure if VS2010 could on it's own.