# Find empty methods in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, replace

How do you find all the empty methods of a specific type defined in a project? an example use case would be to find all empty Page_Load methods defined in an Asp.Net application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2008 / C# : How to find dead code in a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020297/visual-studio-2008-c-sharp-how-to-find-dead-code-in-a-project), [Find unused code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/245963), [Is there a tool for finding unreferenced functions (dead, obsolete code) in a C# app?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/65585), [What tools and techniques do you use to find dead code in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/162641)

Comment: @CodyGray: I don't think this is a duplicate of any of those; this question deals with empty methods that *are* being used (as event handlers) and thus *aren't* dead code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the visual studio find-tool, set it to use Regular Expressions. Use this expression to find empty methods.

```
void\ .*\(*\)(\ |(\r\n))*{(\ |(\r\n))*}
```

To find empty Page_Load methods:

```
void\ (Page_Load).*\(*\)(\ |(\r\n))*{(\ |(\r\n))*}
```

All these approaches would work for "void" methods. For other types, you can change the expression or further generalize the expression to match any kind of return type.

Comment: Even if you answered your question yourself please mark it as solved. I searched for this and my first look told me this question wasnt solved in here so I had to test it. Its a benifit for everyone having a green hook showing a working solution :)

Answer (score 1):

to improve ravinsp's answer a bit, if you want the 'find all' to actually hilight the entire method (so you can do a search and replace to remove them), use regex

```
 ^.*void\ .*\(*\)(\ |(\r\n))*{(\ |(\r\n))*}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (or possibly [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)) to detect empty methods. An FxCop rule for detecting empty methods can be found [here](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/fxcop7.aspx) (although I haven't tested it, you should be able to modify it to avoid removing the methods).